# Template literals Formatting Idea

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Please help me with template literals

```
const myName = 'raju';
const company = 'myHomeCompany';
console.log(`${myName} ${company}`);
```

Now I get the output as raju myHomeCompany which is as expected. But I want the output to be as raju (myHomeCompany ) .

the main thing here is I want to keep the company in parathesis with es6 template literals

Comment: just add the parenthesis.....

Answer (score 2):

Just add the parenthesis .....

```js
const myName = 'raju';
const company = 'myHomeCompany';
console.log(`${myName} (${company})`);
```

Comment: Working Thanks for helping me out